# Apache Superset Default Web Server

Tags: webserver, gunicorn, apache-superset

I have installed Apache Superset in My Machine. I want to know what is default Web server Apache Superset is Used as I did not write any additional code to use Gunicorn/ Nginx/Apache.
Please help me as I am new in Apache Superset.
I have installed Apache Superset based on Installation Manual.

I want to know which Web Server is used for Apache Superset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Superset's `superset run` actually runs [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/)'s very simple built-in development server, which is not designed for production environments. To run Apache Superset in a production environment, Superset recommends running Gunicorn in async mode.  This is how Superset runs when deployed with `docker-compose up` - you'll see in the logs:

```
superset_app          | [2023-08-09 13:08:16 +0000] [14] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
superset_app          | [2023-08-09 13:08:16 +0000] [14] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8088 (14)
superset_app          | [2023-08-09 13:08:16 +0000] [14] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
superset_app          | [2023-08-09 13:08:16 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16
```

Alternatively, you can use Nginx or similar, or run Apache Superset behind a load balancer.

- [Documentation for running Apache Superset on a wsgi-http-server](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset#running-on-a-wsgi-http-server).
- [Gunicorn documentation](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html)

Comment: Thank you. I have find the answer finally. I have installed Gunicorn and used Gunicorn for Superset.
Instead of using default Flask Server:-

superset run -p 8088 --with-threads --reload --debugger
Current Code:- 
gunicorn -w 8 -k gevent --timeout 120 -b IP:PORT --limit-request-line 0 --limit-request-field_size 0 --certfile=.crt file --keyfile=.key file"superset.app:create_app()". 
 I have changed my code and it is working fine